# Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: sudo

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop using VMware Player. I am not sure why but I have an account called "User Account" in addition to my account that I usually login to use Ubuntu. Well that was just a side comment but basically all I am trying to do is install the ncurses library on Ubuntu. I have tried installing ncurses using the following command lines:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
```

When I tried installing ncurses twice using the above commands I received the following prompt in the terminal:

```
[sudo] password for username
```

When I type in my password I receive the following message:

```
username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

So far I have tried enabling the root user ("Super User") account by following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

Here are some of the things the link suggested to do:

> Allow an other user to run sudo. Type the following in the command line:
>
> sudo adduser username sudo
>
> Or
>
> sudo adduser username sudo
>
> logging in as another user. Type the following in the command line:
>
> sudo -i -u username
>
> Enabling the root account. Type the following in the command line:
>
> sudo -i
>
> Or
>
> sudo passwd root

I have tried all of the above command lines and after typing in each command I was prompted for my password. After I entered my password I received the same message as when I tried to install ncurses:

```
fsolano is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: I don't have comment's yet so bare with me here... Question. is fsolano the first user you made with the install of ubuntu? usually that should have admin privileges, if you perform an admin function in a graphical sense does it work for you at all? IE if you open the GUi for user management and try to do something adminy does it work? or tell you you aren't root

Comment: Same question was asked here too ?
http://superuser.com/questions/866582/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported/866600#866600

Comment: if you've a root user with its password set , you can login root using `su` and add urself to sudo group `àdduser username sudo` else , you'll have to boot with live cd/usb and chroot to the installed system , it will log into root by default , set a root password for next cases `passwd` , and add yourself to sudo from there , and reboot , you'll have your username added to sudo and also you'll have root password , in case if sudo still not working , you can handle it ....

Comment: https://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful but traditionally the group that is given sudo access is called "wheel".  Get an account added to that group and they can usually use sudo.  Maybe it's "sudo" in this case but that would be unusual so try wheel anyway if you can get root access or something.  Usually the first account you created when installing your distro gets added to this group.  So you may need to log into that account for access. Sudo itself has a lot of ways it can be configured so it's messages can be less than helpful.

Answer (score 115):

When this happened to me all I had to do to fix it was:

Step 1. Open a terminal window, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
on my system (Debian KDE after setting up as hotkey)

Step 2. Entered root using command `su root`

Step 3. Input root password

Step 4. Input command `apt-get install sudo -y` to install `sudo`

Step 5. Add user to sudoers file by inputting `adduser username sudo`, put your username in place of `username`

Step 6. Set the correct permissions for sudoers file by inputting `chmod  0440  /etc/sudoers`

Step 7. Type `exit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> until you close your terminal window. Shutdown your system completely and reboot.

Step 8. Open another terminal window.

Step 9. Try any sudo command to check if your username is correctly added to sudoers file. I used `sudo echo "Hello World!"`. If your username has been correctly added to the sudoers list then you will get `Hello World!` as the terminal response!

Comment: -1: `cd -` will *not* go to the home directory but to the most recent other directory. `sudo -` will *not* ask for your user password but for you root password. Do *not* edit `/etc/sudoers` manually use `visudo` for that. Typical ubuntu systems have no root password at all but rely completely on sudo.

Comment: @michas You cannot use visudo without sudo in Debian. `vi` solution is also not possible because read-only. Gedit works in my case.

Comment: In debian 8 you can use vi without sudo as root. To write to the read-only file use :wq!

Comment: This also works for me, the great help indeed!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not even able to run `su -`

Comment: Why does `visudo` let me edit and save `/etc/sudoers` but doing `vi /etc/sudoers` doesn't?

Comment: The thing I was missing was: `Step 8. Open another terminal window.` Thank you!

Comment: bash: adduser: command not found

Comment: Wow, I just had to do this with a brand new ubunu 22.04 install.

Comment: The steps described here DO NOT resolve the issue as described in the original question. Creating a user exclusively as a member of the sudo group might allow sudo but its bad practice.

Answer (score 51):

Follow the link to reset your admin password [sounds like you named your admin user account as `user` :)]

- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

After that, login as the admin user and execute the following.

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo,adm fsolano
```

Now you can login as `fsolano` and you should be able to run `sudo` command.

If you get `bash: usermod: command not found` even as root, try:

```
/sbin/usermod -aG sudo,adm fsolano
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I resolved this problem a very long time ago. This is the solution to the issue I had and possibly anyone else may have.

Comment: I still get the message after typing this as well as `adduser NAME sudo`. I think there m,ust be something else. I'm using Debian 7.8.

Comment: This is not sufficient solution in Debian 8.5. ShrikantKhawale's proposal with little additions is the correct here.

Comment: @masi The trick above *does* work in Debian 8.5 (at least here), but only after you log out and back in again.

Comment: @jcoppens is right, works for Debian 8.6 too, only after log out and login

Comment: @fsolano94 if this answer is the solution, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 27):

I am having the same issue with Kali anytime I want to add *newuser* to the sudo group by typing this command:

```
usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

and editing the right section in `/etc/sudoers`.
All crap!

My fix for this nonsense is to copy the line for root below it and changing root to newuser:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I remember the usual method with usermod used to work but is it a bug for the last couple of years now?
it's really nonsense.
anyway, if someone has a better answer, share it please:)

Comment: Same issue on regular debian (9); manually editing `/etc/sudoers` did the trick

Comment: indeed, seems to be a bug. The user is in the sudo group. It was uncommented in /etc/sudoers - however, it didn't work! Only when i manually added as you suggested, it started to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The config file `/etc/sudoers` list, who is allowed to run which commands as which user.

On ubuntu this file contains a line allowing all users of the `sudo` group to run commands as the `root` user.

To check which users are in the sudo group you can type `getent group sudo`. You can also check the groups of your current user by typing `id`.

Probably your current user is not in the sudo group and is therefore not allowed to use the `sudo` command.

Log in as some sudo enabled user if you want to run `sudo`.

Comment: Well thats just the thing. I would login as the admin or root user but I forgot the password when I first installed Ubuntu on my machine.

Comment: sudo:x:27:user   (im not sure what the x or 27 is but I am positive that user is the user account that I do not know/remember the password to)

Comment: @fsolano94, boot into some form of rescue environment (either directly, or booting from installation media), and change the root password. Or edit the `/etc/sudoers` file (preferrably using `visudo(1)`).

Comment: that is the problem. login as another user solves nothing

Answer (score 9):

Follow the instructions to reset the password for your admin user:

- [Lost Password?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)

Then you'll be able to grant sudo permission to your regular user with

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

as you posted in your original question.

By the way: why are you installing ncurses?  Are you compiling something?

Comment: I am programming Tetris in C and am using curses as a cross platform for graphical user interfacing. And yup I am going to follow the link

Comment: is not in sudoers file...

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a user to sudo group for all access right by:

1. Going to your root directory user by `sudo su` (ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
2. Then enter your current user password
3. type `sudo adduser <username> sudo` where username is the name of the user you want to add in the sudoers list
4. For checking if your required user is added succesfully type `getent group sudo` which will show the list of sudo users

Comment: Hi, welcome to Unix SE and congrats for a good first answer. I fixed your formatting a bit, you can learn more about that by clicking on "syntax help" when writing a post.

Comment: This is *not* a good answer. (1) The question states that `sudo` doesn’t work for the user.  (2) The answer `sudo adduser <username> sudo` has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

If you  have any other root/admin user than 'fsolano', that is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported:

```
check sudo enabled users (groups)
# getent group sudo 
sudo:x:27:xyz,abc
```

since the user 'fsolano' is changed to standard user and if you have any other root privileged user, login via the root one and change 'fsolano' to administrator using "User Accounts".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
su root -l -c "echo 'ismail ALL=(ALL)  ALL' >> /etc/sudoers"
```

However, I found a better solution.

```
su root -l -c "adduser ismail sudo"
```

replace `ismail` with your user name.

You have to restart the machine after running this command.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to add an user to `sudoers` file is run the command bellow as user with permission to execute `gpasswd`:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username sudo
```

Comment: This does not work in Debian 8.5.

Answer (score -2):

1.You can check whether you are a part of sudo group or not by using below command

```
groups username ===> it will lists the groups for which he belongs too
```

We can check by below script too

```
h=`groups username| awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| grep -io 'sudo'`
if [[ $h == "sudo" ]]
then
echo "user praveen is part of group sudo"
else
echo "Need to add user to group sudo"
echo "Swictch to root and add user"
fi
```