# What does the error "X is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported." philosophically/logically mean?

Tags: sudo, user-interface

Along side the question "[Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179954/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported)" that explained the programical aspects of the error and suggested some workarounds, I want to know: what does this error mean?

```
X is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

The former part of the error explains, clearly, the error. But the second part says that "This error will be reported"?! But why? Why the error will be reported and where? To whom? I'm both user and administrator and didn't receive any report :)!

Comment: Philosophically?!? Or technically?

Comment: [obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/838/)

Comment: A (good) system silently logs lots of stuff. Lots and lots of stuff. Especially errors. Especially if it consider them to be ill-intentioned. I think that by asking about "philosophically", OP is asking why this specific concrete error warns you in such an intimidating way about the reporting, while most other failures are reported silently. It might just be what the original coder wrote at the moment, but after many version it has never got changed and there could be a deeper meaning. Or maybe not. If this is the focus, I think this is a great question I've wondered quite a few times.

Comment: @steeldriver :)) That Santa makes me feel more like I'm getting fooled.

Comment: This presumably dates back to when you had a whole building using 1 computer and an admin/operator looked after the computer as a full-time job.

Comment: Years ago when I was in university and before `sudo` was a thing, I was trying to do something as root on my personal Linux box. So, I ran `su`. When it rejected my password, I tried again several times thinking I had mistyped my password. Eventually I realized that that terminal was logged into the school's email server. Not long after that, the email server sysadmin asked me why I had tried to get root on his system. So there clearly was some sort of reporting even though it was in the pre-`sudo` days.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Wow that's really interesting! Thanks for sharing your experience. Actually, after I saw that message for the first time I was hoping that someone will call me or send me a message or something threatening me for what I did and then story begins like what happened at the beginning of the Matrix movie to Neo! :-))

Comment: @immibis I work in a place with several multi-user systems. At any point in time, there may be between 10 and 50 people logged in to one of several login nodes. This is not uncommon nor old fashioned.

Comment: The philosophical choice also includes the [lecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107583/382) (which may have been disabled when `sudo` was compiled).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I wouldn't use the term "philosophical choice" but that's a useful thing for keeping users on their toes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The administrator(s) of a system are likely to want to know when a non-privileged user tries but fails to execute commands using `sudo`.  If this happens, it could be a sign of

1. a curious legitimate user just trying things out, or
2. a hacker trying to do "bad things".

Since `sudo` by itself can not distinguish between these, failed attempts to use `sudo` are brought to the attention of the admins.

Depending on how `sudo` is configured on your system, any attempt (successful or not) to use `sudo` will be logged.  Successful attempts are logged for audit purposes (to be able to keep track of who did what when), and failed attempts for security.

On a fairly vanilla Ubuntu setup that I have, this is logged in `/var/log/auth.log`.

If a user gives the wrong password three times, or if they are not in the `sudoers` file, an email is sent to root (depending on the configuration of `sudo`, see below). This is what's meant by "this incident will be reported".

The email will have a prominent subject:

```
Subject: *** SECURITY information for thehostname ***
```

The body of the message contains the relevant lines from the logfile, for example

```
thehostname : Jun 22 07:07:44 : nobody : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=console ; PWD=/some/path ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls
```

(Here, the user `nobody` tried to run `ls` through `sudo` as root, but failed since they were not in the `sudoers` file).

No email is sent if (local) mail has not been set up on the system.

All of these things are configurable as well, and that local variations in the default configuration may differ between Unix variants.

Have a look at the `mail_no_user` setting (and related `mail_*` settings) in the `sudoers` manual (my emphasis below):

> `mail_no_user`
>
> If set, mail will be sent **to the mailto user** if the invoking user is not in the `sudoers` file.  **This flag is on by default**.

Answer (score 17):

In Debian and its derivatives, the `sudo` incident reports are logged to `/var/log/auth.log` which contains system authorization information, including user logins and authentication mechanisms that were used:

```
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for regularjohn: 
regularjohn is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

[as root]

$ tail -n 1 /var/log/auth.log
Jun 21 16:30:26 marvin sudo: regularjohn : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/19 ; PWD=/home/regularjohn ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
```

This log file is typically only accessible to users in the `adm` group, i.e. users with access to [system monitoring tasks](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups):

```
$ ls -la /var/log/auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 76189 Jun 21 16:30 /var/log/auth.log
```

From the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups):

> Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this group can read many log files in /var/log, and can use xconsole. Historically, /var/log was /usr/adm (and later /var/adm), thus the name of the group.

[Users in the `adm` group are usually administrators](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch12.en.html#s12.1.12.3), and this group permission is intended to allow them to read log files without having to `su`.

[By default `sudo` uses the Syslog `auth` facility for logging](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudoers.man.html). `sudo`'s logging behavior can be modified using the `logfile` or `syslog` options in `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d`:

- The `logfile` option sets the path to the `sudo` log file.
- The `syslog` option sets the Syslog facility when [`syslog(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) is being used for logging.

The Syslog `auth` facility is redirected to `/var/log/auth.log` in `etc/syslog.conf` by the presence of the following configuration stanza:

```
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score 8):

Technically, it doesn't mean anything much. Many (if not all) other software logs logins, failed or otherwise. For example `sshd` and `su`:

```
Jun 21 17:52:22 somehost sshd[25807]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
Jun 21 17:52:22 somehost sshd[25807]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 37268 ssh2
Jun 21 17:52:23 somehost sshd[25807]: Connection closed by ::1 port 37268 [preauth]
Jun 21 17:52:28 somehost su[25809]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/15 ruser=someuser rhost=  user=root
Jun 21 17:52:28 somehost su[25809]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Jun 21 17:52:28 somehost su[25809]: FAILED su for root by someuser
```

Also, many systems have some sort of automation for detecting excessive authentication errors to be able to deal with possible brute-force attempts, or just use the information to reconstruct events after problems appear.

`sudo` doesn't do anything especially exceptional here. All the message means is that the author of `sudo` appears to have taken a somewhat aggressive philosophy in communicating with users that happen to run commands they cannot use.

Answer (score 6):

It simply means that someone tried to use the `sudo` command (to access admin privileges), who doesn't have authorization to use it (because they aren't listed in the sudoers file). This could be a hacking attempt or some other sort of security risk, so the message is saying that the attempted use of `sudo` will be reported to the system administrator, so they can investigate.

Comment: Well in my local machine I'm the only user and administrator and I can tell you that I didn't receive any report!

Comment: @Kasramvd you probably did, in some file somewhere. I'm not exactly sure where `sudo` sends the report. In your situation, with only one user, it probably isn't very important.

Comment: @Kasramvd have you checked for an email to the root user? Also, you're the administrator but you don't have sudo for your account? How do you handle privilege escalation?

Comment: @Kasramvd It was not reported to you....

Comment: @Kasramvd You THINK you are the administrator. The OS is clearly telling you that you don't have permission to act as an administrator - you're the hardware's owner at best but that does not necessarily make you an admin

Comment: @slebetman Yes, that's right. It means that the incident will be "reported" too `root`. But when you see the word report you think of a email/message or something. But it seems that it's just a log.